# Firestore service rules for service account

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I need to give write permissions for a particular collection to service accounts only. How to write security rules for that? Is there any field  in request to identify service account?

Answer (score 3):

Service accounts always have full access to all data in Firestore, regardless of any security rules defined for that data.  If you want data to be read only by service accounts, simply reject all access in security rules so that mobile clients will never be able to access it, while service accounts will still always be able to access it.

```
allow read, write: if false;
```

Comment: Does the service account need a specific role?

Comment: @simbolo The general expectation for service accounts that need to make changes to a project is that they should have the Editor role.

Comment: I copied the default service account that Firebase creates when being added to an existing gcloud project, and see that a service account must have either the global Editor role as you mentioned, OR the just the 'Firebase Admin SDK Administrator Service Agent'
and 'Service Account Token Creator' roles specifically, to be able to have read/write access to the Firestore database.